# Where is the file .vimrc in macOS? (Downloaded Macvim through Homebrew)

Tags: macos, mac, homebrew, macvim

I have Yosemite 10.10.3 and I recently downloaded macvim using homebrew. I find a vimrc file under the directory:

> /usr/share/vim

However, after putting some modification like setting the background theme to dark, nothing changed when I opened macvim. Am I doing something wrong? Is it the wrong vimrc file? Does it mean the vimrc file is in a different directory if it was downloaded from homebrew?

Comment: Run `which vim` to see which `vim` installation you are running. Aint 'vim' installed by default?

Comment: I upgraded it with homebrew.

Comment: But that does not by definition replace the previous version. Homebrew installes in /usr/local/bin and (no mac here) to my knowledge vim is installed in /usr/bin. It also depends on your path. Just run which vim once.

Comment: Yes the previous one is not replaced, but after I put the command: brew install vim, and when I put vim in terminal it shows the version is 7.4.712 instead of 7.3 which is shipped with the system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use vim before the installation, the file `.vimrc` should be on your `$HOME` directory (`/Users/your-username/.vimrc`). Macvim will use that file if exists.

Comment: I checked this directory and the file doesn't exist. Does it mean I have to create one?

Comment: Yes, you should create it to customize it only for your user.